# Express and lighttpd as proxy server generate Server 500 error

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, handlebars.js, lighttpd

**Update - it works just fine with nginx so that'll work for now : )**

I'm working on setting up a Node site, using Express and Express handlebars, and using Lighttpd as a reverse proxy server for the site.

The site works fine when I run it locally or bypass the proxy, i.e., go to http://localhost:3000/

However, when I have static content enabled (such as):

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Or simply use handlebars to render a page, on the return I get a Internal Server 500 error from lighttpd.

Such as:

```
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});
```

These both generate a 500 error from Lighttpd.

I've tried:

```
app.set('trust proxy', '127.0.0.1');
```

as well as:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 'localhost');
```

But this doesn't seem to help at all either.  I'm sure its making it to the Node page, as in my app I have console logging and when I don't use Handlebars or static content the page is served no-problem through the proxy.

My lighttpd proxy configuration is:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "\.(html)$" {
   proxy.server  = ( "" => (
     ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 3000 )
      )
   )
   proxy.debug = 100
}
```

I have lighttpd logging turned up as high as I've been able to figure out how to turn it up, however no clues as of yet as to why its turning up a  server 500 error.

Comment: I see your update that you have things working with nginx.  That's good.  Still, I am curious which version of lighttpd you were running.  lighttpd 1.4.42 fixed some proxying issues which you might have run into if you were running lighttpd 1.4.40 or 1.4.41.

Comment: It was 1.4.41 ... I believe I installed it using yum on CentOS 7.  If I get around to it I'll try it with 1.4.42